# How to input a formatted date in a text box?

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I'm confuse about how to make an input of formatted date time and currency. I want user to input the DoB as `dd/mm/yyyy` but when I'm using `DateTime` data type in Visual Studio it only get `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

Here's my code:
This is DoB and  property from another class employee.cs

```
 class employee
    {
        private DateTime myBOD;
public DateTime BOD
        {
            get
            {
                return myBOD;
            }
            set
            {
                myBOD = value;
            }
        }
}
```

This is the main form1.cs

```
vemployee.BOD = Convert.ToDateTime(bod.Text);
var today = DateTime.Today;
age.Text = Convert.ToString(today.Year-vemployee.BOD.Year);
```

Comment: `vemployee.BOD = Parse.Exact(bod.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: (today.Year-vemployee.BOD.Year).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `DateTime` is a `struct` it doesn't have any format but properties like `Year`, `Month`, `Day` etc.
use `DateTime.ParseExact` when you want to obtain `DateTime` from `string`:

```
 vemployee.BOD = DateTime.ParseExact(
   bod.Text, 
  "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", // Please, note that "mm" stands for minutes, not months
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And `.ToString(format)` when you want to represent `DateTime` as a `string`

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

 bod.Text = today.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```